# Google Token refresh issue

Tags: vb.net, google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I need a help for refresh token in my application.

I have done an application in vb.net with Google Calendar API and "OAuth 2.0 client ID".

I gave this application to 10 teams of peoples and each team made up with three or four people.
Every Team share a Calendar (set, read, change, delete events)

Credentials "ID client OAuth 2.0" for every user account was also created, without publish the appication but every people's token needs a refresh every 7 days and I don't like this.

Since I can't force all of them to pupblish the application, Is there a way to avoid this renew?

Other question: Is it possible to connect with API Key insted of "ID client OAuth 2.0" ? If so, I can do the same thing in calendar  (set, read, change, delete events) ?

That's my connection:

```
Dim credentials As UserCredential
Dim CalendarScopes () As String = {CalendarService.Scope.Calendar, CalendarService.Scope.CalendarEvents}

Using stream As New FileStream ("C: \ Test \ credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
                credentials = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync (GoogleClientSecrets.FromStream (stream) .Secrets, CalendarScopes, "user", CancellationToken.None, New FileDataStore ("C: \ Test \ token.json", True)). Result
            End Using
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check the oauth2 documentation under [expiration](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration) you will find it states.

> A Google Cloud Platform project with an OAuth consent screen configured for an external user type and a publishing status of "Testing" is issued a refresh token expiring in 7 days.

You need to publish your application once its in production tokens created by your application will no longer expire.  Note: Everyone doesn't have to publish the application you the developer need to publish your application.  This has nothing to do with the users of your application.

## api keys

APi keys only grant you read access to access public data, not private user data.  Not public data and you wont be able to insert or delete it.

## Project / app / software

You are a developer you went to google cloud console and create a project and a client id for that project.

Then you began to develop your application.  Your application then uses the client id to allow users of your app to grant your application consent to access their data.

For your application to create refresh tokens that last longer then seven days your project in google cloud console must be set to production.

None of the above has anything to do with the users / teams / entities / or groups of people that are running your application.   '

You have a single application with a single project on google cloud console with a single client id.  It is this that needs to be set to production by you the developer it has nothing to do with the users who install your application.

## Oauth docs

[Native-app](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app)

> Any application that uses OAuth 2.0 to access Google APIs must have authorization credentials that identify the application to Google's OAuth 2.0 server. The following steps explain how to create credentials for your project. Your applications can then use the credentials to access APIs that you have enabled for that project.

The author of the application should be creating the clients.  If anyone else did it would probably be against googles TOS,  You need to know how the application works and what it was designed to do.   No user should be creating client credentials for an application they don't know this could be a serous security risk to their account.

Comment: I don't understant, you told me that "Everyone doesn't have to publish the application you the developer need to publish your application. This has nothing to do with the users of your application."

Even though all 10 groups uses my software, no one of the user of the groups share calendar outside of the group, this means that it is intended how if they are 10 different entities standalone.
In this case one user of the group at least have to publish the application or not ?

Comment: project is defined by your client id,  you should only have one client id.  for your application.   This project with your client id needs to be published in order for it to create refresh tokens that last longer then seven days.       Who or what teams use your app is unrelated to wither or not your application is in testing or production.

Comment: See my update Project / app / software

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but I still don't understand

This is what every groups do:

One of the people of the group creates a calendar that share with all people of the group.
Every member of the group go to API Console and create credentials OAuth 2.0 and download the json file.
Every member of the group run my software that use the json file of the user to connect to the shared calendar.

By my side, I do nothing in my app because they doesn't report me nothing, because the application is intended for groups. Every people of the group point directly to the shared calendar and not in my app.

Comment: In practice, how does this actually work with a desktop-based WinForms application where there is no web service, and the client connects directly from the WinForms application to some part of their own Google account?

Comment: yes, you understand me at 100%

Comment: Users of your application should not be creating anything on Google developer console. It is up to you as a developer to create those credentials and compile them into your application.  It will be up to you to have your application go though the verification process.   The verification process is going to require that a web site be set up and declare all of the privacy policy.   This is not something your users  should be doing.    Create a single client and compile it into your application.

Comment: OK thank you, but I didn't create any website. I think I have to do this for first and then go on.
I'll keep in touch

Comment: Have a look at this it will walk you though the steps https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lzIuNmNX9N8

Comment: What do you mean with "It is up to you as a developer to create those credentials and compile them into your application". Is there some documentation ?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app  <--- does not say have your users do it.     I have emailed the team to get their feed back on what you are doing.

Comment: I'm confused. I'm understanding that my app is not working properly, I want to fix it but right now I'm not ready to publish it, so I can only collect infos. Tell me if it is correct:
After publish my app I have to declare all users of all groups inside my app, create credentials json file that can be used for all of them ?

Comment: If your not ready to publish it then it still in test in which case refresh tokens will only be good for seven days.    You should only have test users using it, these users need to be declared in google cloud console.     After you publish your app your app you don't need to declare who is using your app.   Yes you need to create a single credentials file used by all of them.  Compile it into your application.

Comment: OK thank you. Now it is a little bit clear